# Is Utilitarianism based on Calculations or Calculus?

Tags: utilitarianism

I have been going through the Justice lecture series by Harvard and noticed one thing whenever there was reference to Utilitarianism and it's related phenomena like cost-benefit analysis the word calculus was being used by the professor instead of calculations? Having no prior experience in Philosophy I am not sure if this is something which is generally taken for granted or does calculus here really refer to the mathematical foundation of calculus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not refer to the [infinitesimal calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus).

See [Jeremy Bentham: Felicific Calculus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bentham/#FelCal) and [Felicific Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felicific_calculus):

> "The felicific calculus is an algorithm formulated by utilitarian philosopher Jeremy Bentham (1747–1832) for calculating the degree or amount of pleasure that a specific action is likely to cause."

See also [Ethical calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethical_calculus).

Comment: ohh got it thanks :)

Comment: @FoundABetterName - you are welcome :-)